# Why Asus Z68 deluxe wont boot/post (not even q-code led)

Tags: hardware-failure, post

Here are the specs:

- Asus z68 deluxe gen3 rev1 (latest bios 0302)
- i7-2600K (no oc) +    Noctua HSF
- G-Skill sniper 4GBx2 1600MHZ CL9
- Sapphire Pure 1250W
- Gainward GTX460

The thing is my system won't boot, there is no beeps, no q-code LED, no POST and nothing on screen (it was running for half a year now, very important to note).

The fans are working on the HSF/case/fpu and the southbridge have light. The GPU and the CPU both ran with good temps all the time and no OC. Also it is good to mention that the CPU POST state led is lit witch may indicating an error with the CPU but I don't have another CPU to check whether it's board is the problem or the CPU.

Here is what I'v tried:

- I've removed everything and took the board out of the case
- I've cleared CMOS (both by removing the battery and pressing the button the back of the board).
- Replaced ram with another that I've got which I know is good and also tried all positions
- Replaced GPU also
- Took the HSF, reapplied thermal paste mx4 and reseated the CPU

What's next?

Comment: How did the system fail? Would it just suddenly not POST one day? Or did you do work on it or move it and then it wouldn't POST?

Comment: the system was running in idle mode (screen was set to 20 minutes) then i was back typing and the screen wouldn't turn on. (day before the screen was flickering on/off and got a "not supported resolution." and i havnt changed the res. do note that i have 2 screens that both was connected and one was on/off flickering and the other dont.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked using the motherboard video? Also, if you have power supply tester or a multimeter you can check the power supply voltages. Then you are really down to motherboard or cpu. You could buy the cheapest CPU your motherboard supports just for testing. (CELERON G440?)

Comment: the board doesnt have integrated video card http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z68_DELUXEGEN3/ ya i dont have a psu tester that could help. good idea about buying the g440 to check but its 65usd. not sure what to do

Comment: I see, Z68 cards often have display connectors. Around here the cheapest motherboard is more expensive than cheapest cpu, but both are considerably less expensive than the stuff you have. Another option would be return the motherboard. Find out how much you will be charged if they determine that it is OK.

Comment: yes maybe il do it doday or tommorow, the thing is i think i may take both board and cpu to the seller or just one of them

Comment: hello all iv bought a psu tester and psu is the problem. i took the board and the cpu to the store and they see that the board and cpu are both ok. does sapphire known to have probs with their psus?

Comment: My impression is that power supply problems are more common now than, say, five or ten years ago. That could easily be just a relative thing, that the other components have become more reliable.